# Generics and casting to the right type

Tags: java, generics

My problem can be summed-up by this snippet:

```
public interface TheClass<T> {
    public void theMethod(T obj);
}

public class A {
    private TheClass<?> instance;

    public A(TheClass<?> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void doWork(Object target) {
        instance.theMethod(target); // Won't compile!

        // However, I know that the target can be passed to the
        // method safely because its type matches.
    }
}
```

My class `A` uses an instance of `TheClass` with its generics type unknown. It features a method with a target passed as `Object` since the `TheClass` instance can be parameterized with any class. However, the compiler won't allow me to pass the target like this, which is normal.

**What should I do to circumvent this issue?**

A dirty solution is to declare the instance as `TheClass<? super Object>`, which works fine but is semantically wrong...

Another solution I used before was to declare the instance as raw type, just `TheClass`, but it's bad practice, so I want to correct my mistake.

**Solution**

```
public class A {
    private TheClass<Object> instance; // type enforced here

    public A(TheClass<?> instance) {
        this.instance = (TheClass<Object>) instance; // cast works fine
    }

    public void doWork(Object target) {
        instance.theMethod(target); 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, for a good question!! waiting for the answers...

Comment: A is part of an open-source library I made which is used by a lot of people, and typing A would mean a strong api break. I discovered this issue lately because I used raw types for the "TheClass" instance before, since I wasn't aware that it was bad conception. It worked just fine, but is considered bad practice so I want to correct this misuse.

Comment: This is a side note, but you can call a method `do` it is a reserved word.

Comment: How is it an API break? People will only get a warning that A should be typed, but their code will still work as before, because of Java type erasure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private TheClass<Object> instance;

    public A(TheClass<Object> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void do(Object target) {
        instance.theMethod(target); 
    }
}
```

or

```
public class A<T> {
    private TheClass<T> instance;

    public A(TheClass<T> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void do(T target) {
        instance.theMethod(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is just what I was typing; but you got there first!

Comment: Your first idea sent me to the solution, thanks! Actually, I enforce the Object type in the declaration of the instance field, like you. However, I still allow wildcard in the constructor parameter, but cast this instance to the enforced type. This only has an effect at compile time, and will not require anything from my users (see last edit of the question).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to also type `A`. Using a wildcard `?` makes you loose the type information of `TheClass` and there is no way to recover it later. There are some ugly hacks you could do but your best shot is to also type `A`:

```
public interface TheClass<T> {
    public void theMethod(T obj);
}

public class A<T> {
    private TheClass<T> instance;

    public A(TheClass<T> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void doIt(T target) {
        instance.theMethod(target); 
    }
}
```

It won't break any API either.

Comment: +1, thanks. Typing A is not a possibility for me, as it would add useless complexity to the library, but you're right, that was one of the only few solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ***reason*** for the compile error is that the `?` wildcard indicates the *unknown* type in Java. You may *declare* a variable with an unknown generic parameter, but you cannot *instantiate* one with it. Which means that the in your constructor the passed in generic class could have been created to hold types that are incompatible with what you are trying to later on use. Case in point:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheClass<String> stringHolder = null; // should constrain parameters to strings
        A a = new A(stringHolder);
        a.donot(Float.valueOf(13)) ; // this is an example of what could happen
    }

    private TheClass<?> instance;

    public A(TheClass<?> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void do(Object target) {
        instance.theMethod(target); 
    }
}
```

In this case the compiler is preventing you from writing code that would have been prone to bugs. As others have pointed out, you should add a generic parameter type to your `A` class, in order to constrain the allowed types - that will remove the compile time error.

Some suggested reading: [Oracle Generics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Thanks. I learnt generics theory in deep details over the past days to resolve this issue, so I understand its mechanisms. I wouldn't have been in such situation if I knew the theory before using raw types all over the place. Now that it's done, I was trying to remove raw types, but ran into this issue.

Comment: Anyway, your code will fail at runtime, throwing an exception and stopping the program. That's fine, it's like an implicit assertion and the error will show users that there is a mistake in their code. It won't be a compile time error, but it's still an error and there won't be undefined behavior, just fresh and clean crash with debug stacktrace :) +1 for your example though, it will help people to understand why compile-time verification is important.

Comment: @AurélienRibon - The code I posted is for illustration purposes only. I did change the `do` method to a `donot`, but thats as far as I corrected errors.